# How can I skip errors and continue running the SQL-query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

I am writing a piece of code with the intention of searching through all databases in the server for a certain table name, however I ran into some trouble since I do not have permission to read/access all databases in the server.

I am wondering if there is a way for the query to advance if one statement is not available due to security permissions (i.e. if I have ten databases in a particular server with no access to the fourth, I would want it to run 1-2-3 and then 5-6-7-8-9-10 with returned results).

I have tried using TRY-CATCH, but I cannot seem to get the code to bypass the initial problem which is stopping when the security permissions are not available.

```
declare @tabell varchar(254) = 'JE' -- table name which is supposed to be 
--found.

-- STEP 1: lists all available databases in the server with a row number.
drop table if exists #steg1 select name, row_number() over (order by 
name) as rownumber into #steg1 from sys.databases

-- STEP 2: generates code for all databases in order to identify those 
--with the table name @tabell.
drop table if exists #steg2 select 1 Ordn,'use '+name+' drop table if 
exists #hitta select * into #hitta from sys.tables where name = 
'''+ltrim(@tabell)+'''' as script into #steg2 from #steg1 a 
where rownumber =1
union
select 2 Ordn, 'use '+name+' insert into #hitta select * from sys.tables 
where name = '''+ltrim(@tabell)+'''' from #steg1 a
where rownumber >1
union
select 3 Ordn,'select * from #hitta' as x

-- STEP 3: concatenate the generated code into a single string.
declare @string varchar(max)
select @string = concat(@string + ' ', '')+ script from #steg2
drop table if exists #steg3 select @string as string into #steg3

-- STEP 4: exec the code concatenated in the previous step.
declare     @cmd    varchar(max)
begin 
set @cmd = (select string from #steg3)
exec (@cmd)
end
```

Getting the error message: Msg 916, level 14, state 1, stating that the user cannot access the database under the current security context.

Comment: Which database are you using? Oracle, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, or other?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue using has_dbaccess(database), below you can see how I incorporated it into the code.

```
declare @tabell varchar(254) = 'JE' -- table name which is 
supposed to be found.

-- STEP 1: lists all available databases in the server with a row number.
drop table if exists #steg1 select name, row_number() over (order by name) as rownumber 
into #steg1 from (SELECT name, has_dbaccess(name) access FROM sys.databases) a where 
access = 1

-- STEP 2: generates code for all databases in order to identify those with the table 
--name @tabell.
drop table if exists #steg2 select 1 Ordn,'use '+name+' drop table if exists #hitta 
select name as [Table], cast('''+name+'''as varchar(max)) as [Databas] into #hitta from 
sys.tables where name = '''+ltrim(@tabell)+'''' as script into #steg2 from #steg1 a 
where rownumber =1
union
select 2 Ordn, 'use '+name+' insert into #hitta select name as [Table], 
cast('''+name+'''as varchar(max)) as [Databas] from sys.tables where name = 
'''+ltrim(@tabell)+'''' from #steg1 a
where rownumber >1
union
select 3 Ordn,'select * from #hitta' as x

-- STEP 3: concatenate the generated code into a single string.
declare @string varchar(max)
select @string = concat(@string + ' ', '')+ script from #steg2
drop table if exists #steg3 select @string as string into #steg3

-- STEP 4: exec the code concatenated in the previous step.
declare     @cmd    varchar(max)
begin 
set @cmd = (select string from #steg3)
exec (@cmd)
end
```